# AudioRecord: "Overrun user" logs - what do they mean?

Tags: android, audio, audiorecord

I have a simple piece of code that creates an AudioRecord object, then uses it to record to a file. It is pretty standard and seems to work perfectly fine. I am using a Samsung GalaxyS Vibrant running stock Android 2.2.

However, I am getting messages such as these in logcat at different intervals:

```
04-13 14:03:30.754: V/AudioRecord(4831): Overrun user: 820, server: 1040, flowControlFlag 0
04-13 14:03:30.766: V/AudioRecord(4831): Overrun user: 820, server: 1040, flowControlFlag 1
```

Does anyone know what these mean? Am I overrunning the internal audio buffer and losing audio frames? It doesn't seem like it from the recorded file, but these intermittent messages are worrying me a bit.

Comment: Some code, especially the part which throws the error would be helpful.

Comment: It's a standard set of calls: creating an AudioRecord object and running startRecording() on it. Like I said it works perfectly fine, but it shows these messages, which are internal Samsung logs that others have seen as well (there are some other questions in SO about turning them off - can't do it). All I am wondering about is an idea of what they actually mean however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems this is an internal log used by some samsung devices. So you can not hide them but it is not harmful either. If you dont want to see it you can just filter out this from your logcat

Comment: It's not about not wanting to see them (there are other questions about that already). I am rather wondering what they actually mean and if I should be worried about them.

Comment: as it is only a log used by device, it is not harmful

Answer (score 6):

This might be a little late, but this is merely a log message (not specifically Samsung, I've seen it with different makes, models & brands) telling you that you've started recording, but are not reading out the data from the AudioRecord.

Hence the `Overrun user`, the AudioRecord's buffers are full.

Comment: It's rather simple. As soon as you start recording, read out the audio, and keep reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
```

this permission is necessary

Answer (score 0):

I think is because read pcm data too slow, I faced the same question, when I do a little sleep between two read operations, this log become more when I set the sleep time longer.
So I think there is 2 ways to resolve this problem:
1.make read operation quick
2.make the buffer bigger, when you new a AudioRecorder set last para to 2*minBufferSize or bigger. It can allow you read more data every read operation.
Hope your can understand that, sorry for my poor english.